# Deleting a specific data from a text file in Python

Tags: python, file

My question is about deleting a specific data (like phone number) from a file and save this file after deleting.

I'm trying to make a simple phonebook app in Python. I have a .txt file which contains phone numbers. Like this:

```
09143630568,09014317978,
```

All in one line.

And I have a function that deletes a specific number that user wants:

```
def DeleteNumbers(number):
    print(f"Deleting {number} from the list...")
    try:
        with open(phonebook, 'r') as phonebook_file:
            AllNumbers = phonebook_file.read()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Oops! File not found!!!")
    else:
        AllNumbers = AllNumbers.split(",")
    if str(number) in AllNumbers:
        AllNumbers.remove(str(number))
        print("The number has been deleted successfully :)\n")
    else:
        print(False)
```

I want to delete the number entirely from the file but I don't know how to do it correctly. Any idea?

Comment: I'd use regular expressions to find and replace the phone number. But however you choose to do it, after you've changed the data, you just need to write it back to disk. (This is the programmatic version of having forgotten to click save.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the number from the file, You need to write it inside the else block -

```
def DeleteNumbers(number):
    print(f"Deleting {number} from the list...")
    try:
        with open(phonebook, 'r') as phonebook_file:
            AllNumbers = phonebook_file.read()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Oops! File not found!!!")
    else:
        AllNumbers = AllNumbers.split(",")
        if str(number) in AllNumbers:
            AllNumbers.remove(str(number))
            with open(phonebook, 'w') as phonebook_file:
                phonebook_file.write(",".join(AllNumbers))
            print("The number has been deleted successfully :)\n")
        else:
            print(False)
```